# Исключить загрузку отдельных элементов при загрузке страницы html

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня такая ситуация, на сайте есть камеры, когда страница загрузилась камера считывает просмотр хотя она не открывалась, все из-за того что страница полностью прогрузилась.
Я подумал что можно исключить загрузку отдельных элементов и загрузке страницы и открывать их при как обычно при клике.
Если есть у кого-то решение буду очень благодарен!

мы ведём трансляцию камеры выводим таким образом

```
<div id="popup" style="display: none;">
  <div class="iv-embed" style="margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; border: 0; height: 360;">
    <div class="iv-v" style="display: block; margin: 0; padding: 1px; border: 0; background: #000;"><iframe width="100%" height="500" src="rrtsp.me/embed/a3i6eadN" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Мне нужно отложить загрузку этого блока, а после клика загружать

Comment: Из твоего описания мало чего понял... Но страницу можно модифицировать в любое время. Так же программно можно подгружать как скрипты, так и стили. Т.е. страница может быть очень динамичной.

Comment: я хочу исключить загрузку камер, что бы не было просмотров

Comment: Может тогда Вы объясните что это за "камеры" и каким образом они загружается на страницу. Понятно что Вы в контексте своей задачи, но все остальные не совсем понимают о чем речь вообще. Так-то Вы можете отложить загрузку скрипта/видео/изображения/чего угодно до определенного действия.

Comment: у нас камеры подключаются через https://ru.ivideon.com/, мы ведём трансляцию
камеры выводим таким образом 
<div id="popup" style="display: none;"><div class="iv-embed" style="margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; border: 0; height: 360;"><div class="iv-v" style="display: block; margin: 0; padding: 1px; border: 0; background: #000;"><iframe width="100%" height="500" src="https://rrtsp.me/embed/a3i6eadN/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div></div>


как Вы и сказали мне нужно отложить загрузку этого блока, а после клика загружать

Comment: Пример кода вставь в свой вопрос. Там же можно код отформатировать или вообще (что лучше) сделать запускаемым... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> мне нужно отложить загрузку этого блока, а после клика загружать

Вот вариант "загрузки" по клику на кнопку...

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', _ => {
  const html = `<div id="popup" style="display: none;">
    <div class="iv-embed" style="margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; border: 0; height: 360;">
      <div class="iv-v" style="display: block; margin: 0; padding: 1px; border: 0; background: #000;"><iframe width="100%" height="500" src="rrtsp.me/embed/a3i6eadN" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    </div>
  </div>`
  document.querySelector('section').innerHTML = html
})
```

```html
<button>Загрузить</button>
<section></section>
```

Comment: большое спасибо, все работает